# The euro sign in JSP is causing warning that results in a ? instead of the €

Tags: java, jsp, web

In my JSP page the euro sign is causing a warning and presenting as a ? on the web page. The warning is, name.jsp contains characters that will probably be damaged during conversion to the ISO-8859-1 character set.

Comment: ISO-8859-1 doesn't contain the Euro sign. You need ISO-8859-15 for that (or just use UTF-8)

Comment: As browsers interprete ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) actually as Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1), you can convert to `"Windows-1252"` and lie to the browser saying it is ISO-8859-1. Best would be UTF-8 to have all chars, also for Greek. As ISO-8859-15 lacks some other Windows Latin-1 chars, like comma-like quotes, I do not like it.